# How to update value to be the same one with addition?

Tags: sql, asp.net

Is there a way in SQL to update an existing value to be himself with a new value ?

For example : 
I have a value "992", and I want to add "135" so it will be "992135".

I tried doing this :

```
 string sql1 = "UPDATE [Table1] SET OldValue = OldValue " + ValueToAdd;
```

But it just sums it up (ends up to be 992+135 = 1127).

Thanks

Comment: You need to convert both values so they are strings (varchar in sql server). This is also a good reason to use Parameters instead of string concatenation. You can also use sql servers [CONCAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) if using sql server

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: @Nadlir . . . What is the data type of the column?  What database are you using?  Why are you not using parameters?

Comment: Hey, I'm using MS Access DB 2010. And the type of column is Text.
About why I'm not using parameters - I just want to prevent an unnecessary connection to the database, and was wondering if there was a way to do so!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking either for string concatenation or arithmetic, depending on the type of the column.  The standard concatenation operator is `||`, although many databases support the `concat()` function:

```
UPDATE [Table1]
    SET OldValue = CONCAT(OldValue, ValueToAdd);
```

Or, as arithmetic:

```
UPDATE [Table1]
    SET OldValue = OldValue * 1000 + ValueToAdd;
```

Comment: The first solution seems to be the one I am looking for, since the second one will not let me add "987523" with "4542" or even "asdfsdgsd" with "324rds".

I'm not sure if I was clear, but I want to add 2 strings to each others.